# I am taking a course on utilizing Python for Finance. Having trouble importing with Mac terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, anaconda, command

I am taking a Udemy course Python for Finance. I am using Python 3 on my Mac. The course is having me import modules, a particular module requires me to enter the command "pip install pandas-datareader" however this command is doing nothing in my terminal. Legitimately nothing happens. I have tried a multitude of other steps - however nothing entered into the terminal does anything at all. As I am not extremely familiar with computers and Macs, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please assist.

[image of my terminal upon entering diff pip commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDqdC.png)

I was expecting to have the command "pip install pandas-datareader run successfully in my terminal which would then allow me to import pandas-datareader in Anaconda. Or I would expect some indication that the terminal commands failed. However I get nothing which is extremely frustrating.

Comment: Looks like you are entering commands into jupyter and not the original OS terminal.

Comment: NIck, you can run the conda or pip install commands inside Jupyter but you should put the magic symbol in front of them. For example, `%pip install pandas pandas-datareader` run inside a cell in your notebook. Then restart the kernel and run the appropriate imports and they should work. Thuse of the magic symbol in conjunction with the install commands run inside the active notebook where you want to work with the packages has the advantage that the installs occur in the same environment where the kernel is running that underlies the active notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing this straight from the Terminal where you've already opened a Jupyter notebook or something of the sort and then you are trying to enter commands there. That won't do anything, instead you need to enter these commands from a new shell.

Try doing this: open a new Terminal Window (search from the Search Bar or right (or double finger on Macbook) click on the Terminal icon and choose 'New Window' from the menu) and first check the python version. This is done by typing in `python --version`. You should get something like this:

```
Python 3.x.x
```

depending on your install. Then you can go ahead and try running this:

```
python -m pip install pandas-datareader
```

This will set up the library pretty easily and you shouldn't run into any problems even when you run scripts on Jupyter notebooks. Happy coding!